# What is the canonical question to close "layers with the same CRS not overlapping" questions as duplicate of?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, duplicate-questions, canonical

What is the canonical question to close "layers with the same CRS not overlapping" questions as duplicate of?

In particular when the user has *set* a projection/CRS (incorrectly) instead of *reprojecting* the data.

I just went to vote to close a question as duplicate, but couldn't find the older question I was thinking of.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The duplicate targets that I propose for such questions depend on the software being asked about:

- for ArcMap, I use [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not)
- for QGIS, I suggest [Layer disappears when changing from CRS in degrees to CRS in meters in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348521/layer-disappears-when-changing-from-crs-in-degrees-to-crs-in-meters-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

For GeoPandas questions, I suggest: the following question which uses `gdf.set_crs(epsg=projected_crs)` to try and reproject a GeoDataset from geographic instead of `to_crs`

- [GeoPandas Spatial Join of Points and Polygons returns NaN after projecting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/418641/2856)